# Does AWS support multicast and IGMP snooping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multicast

In order to make optimal use of network bandwidth in a communication 1->n I need to use multicast. In an on-premise datacenter with switch having IGMP snooping, the advantage of multicast is obvious. However, in IaaS like AWS this is not obvious as we are abstracted from the HW infrastructure. The problem comes when you need to transmit around 400 Mbps to more than one EC2 instances that may be hosted in any physical server. So this why I'm asking whether AWS supports multicast and IGMP snooping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically, [AWS VPCs have not supported multicast](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#Routing_Topology).

The AWS engineers have recently developed a *proof-of-concept* multicast overlay, that has support for IGMP snooping.

See [Overlay Multicast in Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/6234671078671125)

This is only proof-of-concept and is not yet fully supported.

Comment: +1 for this find, but it doesn't look like something that would need to be "supported," since GRE tunnels between instances already *do* work inside VPC (but not EC2-Classic).

Answer (score 3):

**Update as of December 2019**, Yes, AWS now supports Multicasting via AWS Transit Gateway

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/run-ip-multicast-workloads-aws-transit-gateway/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-multicast-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS launched a VPC service that supports multicasting: **AWS Transit Gateway**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-transit-gateway-adds-multicast-and-inter-regional-peering/

Answer (score 0):

It is supported now and supported in AWS ECS also. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/working-with-multicast.html